# Laptop: If an external screen does not work

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, display, hp-pavilion

On my laptop, (**HP Pavilion DV2**), the screen stopped functioning.

I´ve tried using an external display via **VGA**, but it doesn't work.

I´ve tried using a different external display via **HDMI**, but that also, does not work.

What is the most likely explanation?

1 . Something on the motherboard is broken, e.g. the videocard, the
    graphics-card, or the .....?

2 . The screen itself is dead

3 . Something else: ....?

Comment: If the external display does not work with the VGA and you are certain the external display function is has been enabled (FN + some F button) then the graphics display has gone bad. Unfortunately with that laptop, the graphics display would be built into the motherboard so you would have to replace the whole motherboard.

Comment: where did you find that the `graphics display would be built into the motherboard`? Please provide a link.

Comment: By having experience with laptops, looking the motherboard picture and looking up what graphics it has, I know it's soldered to the motherboard.

Comment: @gwenkillerby Laptop GPUs are (almost?) always soldered to the motherboard.

Comment: @davidgo yeah basically almost always. There are some laptops that have an MXM slot. I wish it was something that would catch on more. You can read more on the [MXM wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_PCI_Express_Module)